# Boost Spirit v2 equivalent to classic as_lower_d

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

Spirit Classic had `as_lower_d[]`, which was very helpful if you wanted to match a keyword case-insensitive.

I am unable to find a similar parser in Spirit v2 / Qi.

What would be "the correct way" to do the following in Qi?

```
rule = as_lower_d[ "keyword" ] >> "=" ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want the `no_case` directive:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/no_case.html

Comment: Yes. And I have this eerie feeling of "I've been looking at [this doc page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/quick_reference/qi_parsers/directive.html) *while typing the question*. Was that really there before? And why didn't I see it?" --- thanks.

Comment: You probably didn't see it as they inverted the naming logic w.r.t your  expectation :) FWIW I think the new name is better (although it still can lead to confusions, see e.g. [_When `symbols` is used for case-insensitive parsing (in a `no_case` directive), added symbol strings should be in lowercase_](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/string/symbols.html))